# How can I develop a custom transpiler using NLP?

Tags: compilation, compiler-construction, transpiler

There are ~500k code snippets written in proprietary language that I have to port to a new system also using its own proprietary language. I have the following with me

- Vocabulary and grammar of source and destination languages
- Sample of 1500 converted rules (for training if required) of different complexity

I am not looking for 100% automation but may be a transpiler that may automate part of it. Can it be done using NLP? Have already gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29193069/how-do-i-start-writing-a-transpiler-is-it-even-possible), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59616963/abstract-programming-language-built-to-transpile), [Rascal](https://www.rascal-mpl.org/help/) , [Haxe](https://haxe.org/) and [Spoofax](http://www.metaborg.org/en/latest/source/langdev/meta/lang/dynsem/index.html). I could not find much documentation on how to create a custom tranpiler.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide an example of these languages?

Comment: NLP means Natural Language Processing. If we are talking about computer languages or other non natural, it is other science - Theory of compilers and transpilers